# Erase Previously selected data

Tags: vba, autocad

I am currently working on a drawing generating code for AutoCAD, in order for the drawing to be generated certain options have to be chosen , and when a wrong option is chosen the person can be able to click on back to go and rectify the option. Here is my code below, the problem is that the code does not erase the previously selected data when "back" is clicked, for example, if I choose "SBPP" the click enter and it takes me to "Louvres" option, then I want to go back and change from "SBPP" to "STD Piping", the previously selected "SBPP" must be erased :

```
Sub DWG ()
    Pump: ans = InputBox("1 = STD Piping" & vbCrLf & _
               "2 = Omit Pump" & vbCrLf & _
               "3 = SBPP", "Pump Piping")

    Select Case ans

    Case "1":
    : Set layerObj = ThisDrawing.Layers.Add("PUMP_PIPING_" & Size)
                layerObj.LayerOn = True
    Case "2":

    : Set layerObj = ThisDrawing.Layers.Add("OMIT_PUMP_" & Size)
                layerObj.LayerOn = True
    Case "3":

    : Set layerObj = ThisDrawing.Layers.Add("STBP_" & Size)
                layerObj.LayerOn = True


    Case Else: MsgBox "Wrong Input Dude.", vbCritical, MSG: Exit Sub

    End Select

 '______________________________________________________________________________
    'Option for Louvres

        Louver: ans = InputBox("1 = STD Louvers" & vbCrLf & _
                "2 = IND louvers" & vbCrLf & _
               "3 = Back ", "Pump Piping")

    Select Case ans

    Case "1":

    : Set layerObj = ThisDrawing.Layers.Add("LOUVRES_STD")
                layerObj.LayerOn = True

    Case "2":

    : Set layerObj = ThisDrawing.Layers.Add("LOUVRES_INDUS")
                layerObj.LayerOn = True

    Case "3":

    If ans = 3 Then
    GoTo Pump
    End If

    Case Else: MsgBox "Wrong Input Dude.", vbCritical, MSG: Exit Sub

    End Select
End Sub
```

How can I modify this code so that when "back" is clicked it erases previously selected data?

Answer (score 1):

This is a flow logic problem. You must use cycles to accomplish your target. "Undoing" your previous options was not defined by you, I'm guessing:

```
Sub DWG()
    Dim ans1 As String, ans2 As String, err_msg As String

    Do 'This cycle will begin and repeat when [Back] is choosen

        Select Case ans1 'Undo previous operation
        Case 1
            ThisDrawing.Layers("PUMP_PIPING_" & size).Delete
        Case "2"
            ThisDrawing.Layers.Add("OMIT_PUMP_" & size).Delete
        Case "3"
            ThisDrawing.Layers.Add("STBP_" & size).Delete
        End Select


        err_msg = ""

        Do 'This cycle will repeat until first answer is accepted
            ans1 = InputBox(err_msg & _
                          "1 = STD Piping" & vbCrLf & _
                          "2 = Omit Pump" & vbCrLf & _
                          "3 = SBPP", "Pump Piping")

            Select Case ans1
            Case "1"
                Set layerObj = ThisDrawing.Layers.Add("PUMP_PIPING_" & size)
                layerObj.LayerOn = True
            Case "2"
                Set layerObj = ThisDrawing.Layers.Add("OMIT_PUMP_" & size)
                layerObj.LayerOn = True
            Case "3"
                Set layerObj = ThisDrawing.Layers.Add("STBP_" & size)
                layerObj.LayerOn = True
            Case "" '[Cancel] button
                Exit Sub
            Case Else
                err_msg = "Wrong Input Dude." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                ans1 = ""
            End Select
        Loop While ans1 = ""

        err_msg = ""
        Do
            ans2 = InputBox(err_msg & _
                          "1 = STD Louvers" & vbCrLf & _
                          "2 = IND louvers" & vbCrLf & _
                          "3 = Back ", "Pump Piping")

            Select Case ans2
            Case "1"
                Set layerObj = ThisDrawing.Layers.Add("LOUVRES_STD")
                layerObj.LayerOn = True
            Case "2"
                Set layerObj = ThisDrawing.Layers.Add("LOUVRES_INDUS")
                layerObj.LayerOn = True
            Case "3"
                'Do nothing, loop control
            Case "" '[Cancel] button
                Exit Sub
            Case Else
                err_msg = "Wrong Input Dude." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                ans2 = ""
            End Select
        Loop While ans2 = ""
    Loop While ans2 = "3"
End Sub
```

Also made some changes:

1. Handle [Cancel] button;
2. Merged error messages in input box, so user doesn't have to press a lot a buttons when a mistake is done;
3. Made a more traditional code formatting

Part II - *"Ask before doing"* alternative

```
Sub DWG()
    Dim ans1, ans2

    ans1 = Choose(Val(InputBox("1 = STD Piping" & vbCrLf & "2 = Omit Pump" & vbCrLf & "3 = SBPP", "Pump Piping")), "PUMP_PIPING_", "PUMP_PIPING_", "PUMP_PIPING_")
    If IsNull(ans1) Then MsgBox "Wrong Input Dude.": Exit Sub

    ans2 = Choose(Val(InputBox("1 = STD Louvers" & vbCrLf & "2 = IND louvers")), "LOUVRES_STD", "LOUVRES_INDUS")
    If IsNull(ans2) Then MsgBox "Wrong Input Dude.": Exit Sub

    ThisDrawing.Layers.Add(ans1 & Size).LayerOn = True
    ThisDrawing.Layers.Add(ans2).LayerOn  = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the changes @LS_ᴅᴇᴠ but the code is still doing the same thing, when an option is chosen in the input box, the layer is switched on with a  drawing and when you click back, it doesn't erase the previous drawing layer, instead it creates a different drawing on top of it and creates a clumsy drawing.

Comment: Of course it doesn't... That "undo" code is not specified by you. Let me check

Comment: @Kwesi, maybe you shouldn't undo at all. Ask user for option and make changes just after all options are confirmed.

Comment: what syntax can I add to switch off all layers at once ?

Comment: @Kwezi Check answer Part II.